# Incorrect day format returned from momentJS countdown

Tags: angularjs, momentjs, countdown

I used this simple script from: https://github.com/icambron/moment-countdown to make a simple countdown. The code below i'm using.

> **Used Code:**

```
$interval(function(){

    $scope.nextDate = moment().countdown($scope.nextDateGet,
        countdown.DAYS|countdown.HOURS|countdown.MINUTES|countdown.SECONDS
    );

    $scope.daysCountdown = moment($scope.nextDate).format('dd');
    $scope.hoursCountdown = moment($scope.nextDate).format('hh');
    $scope.minutesCountdown = moment($scope.nextDate).format('mm');
    $scope.secondsCountdown = moment($scope.nextDate).format('ss');

},1000,0);
```

> **This gives correct output**

```
$scope.nextDate.toString();
```

But this contains one string with the remaining days,hours,minutes and seconds. So i decided i want to split this string into 4 strings by using this:

```
$scope.daysCountdown = moment($scope.nextDate).format('dd');
$scope.hoursCountdown = moment($scope.nextDate).format('hh');
$scope.minutesCountdown = moment($scope.nextDate).format('mm');
$scope.secondsCountdown = moment($scope.nextDate).format('ss');
```

> **Example for input**

```
2016-10-15 10:00:00 // $scope.nextDateGet
```

> **Desired output is something like this:**

```
0 // (days)
12 // (hours)
24 // (minutes)
30 // (seconds)
```

> **But i can't seem to format the remainings days, i get this output:**

```
Fr // Shortcode for the day the item is scheduled => I need the remaining days in this case that would be 0. The other formatting is correct.
```

Comment: `$scope.daysCountdown = moment($scope.nextDate).format('D');` seems to be valid. Only doesn't work if remaining days is `0`. It will set remaining days to `14`.

Comment: If `$scope.nextDate.toString()` has the correct output, and you just want to split it into 4, can you not just do `$scope.nextDate.toString().split(',')` to get an array of four strings? I don't think you want to call `moment()` on the output of `countdown()`, judging by the output on the demo site.

Comment: @Mike McCaughan True but also the auto formatting text like ... Days ... Hours ... Minuts ... Seconds needs to be removed from the string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **The following output was correct if remaining days was not 0:**

```
$scope.daysCountdown = moment($scope.nextDate).format('D');
```

> **If remaining days was 0 it would set remaining days on 14 so this work around did the trick:**

```
if(moment($scope.nextDate).isSame(moment(), 'day')){
    $scope.daysCountdown = 0;
} else {
    $scope.daysCountdown = moment($scope.nextDate).format('D');
}
```

Any suggestions to improve this code are always welcome.